# std::map question on C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory-management, operator-keyword, stdmap

I've a incertitude about std::map on c++:

I did a Object `C_Configuration` that loads a linked library (.so) `C_ConfigurationLibrary`.

The `C_Configuration` class has a `std::map` and `The C_ConfigurationLibrary` has a method that initializes the `std::map`.

If I access to the `std::map` from `C_Configuration` with a "for" loop:

```
std::map<const char*, const char*>::iterator l_item;
for(l_item = m_configuration_map.begin();
    l_item != m_configuration.end();
    l_item++)
```

This is OK;

But if I use :

```
m_configuration[VALUE_KEY] // the value is NULL
```

This is not OK;

My CODE:

```
C_Configuration::C_Configuration()
{
    m_configuration = LoadLibrary(); // load the linked library (.so)

    if(m_configuration != NULL)
    {
        // DEBUG
        LOG_DEBUG("Loading Key from plugin...");

        m_configuration->LoadKeys(m_configuration_map);

        std::map <const char*, const char*>::iterator l_item;
        for ( l_item = l_configuration_map.begin();
              l_item != l_configuration_map.end();
              l_item++ )
        {                
            //THIS IS OK             
        }

        m_configuration_map[FIRST_KEY] // THIS IS NOT OK
    }
}

void C_ConfigLibrary::LoadKeys(std::map<const char*, const char*>& p_configuration_map)
{
    // DEBUG
    LOG_DEBUG("Loading Keys...");

    p_configuration_map.insert ( std::make_pair<const char*, const char*>(FIRST_KEY, FIRST_VALUE) );
    // DEBUG
    LOG_DEBUG("Loaded Key DBUS used: %s",m_dbus_used.c_str());
    p_configuration_map.insert ( std::make_pair<const char*, const char*>(SECOND_KEY,SECOND_VALUE) );
}
```

Can you help me?

thanks so much

Comment: What does "THIS IS NOT OK" mean? That is returned? Does it crash? Also you have 2 left-brakets "}" too many which unnessessarily makes the code less intuative to read.

Comment: You are using `m_configuration[VALUE_KEY]` but you have not inserted `VALUE_KEY` into the map. Is that the problem?

Comment: "THIS IS NOT OK" mean that the return value is "NULL", the source code is an Example, if there are some error as "}", ignore they please, the code compiles and runs. I think that is a problem of memory access, that depend on std::map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `const char*`s as keys, but pointers are compared on their memory addresses and not the text to which they point.  Consequently, when you have a string literal in the shared library, and the same text in a string literal in the main app object, they can have different addresses and will not compare equal as keys.

You're much better off using `std::string`s as the keys, although it's safe to use `const char*` as the values.

FWIW, if you use `const char*` as a key, not only are string literals from different translation units sometimes finicky like this, but you'll have difficultly using text from local buffers, even `std::string`'s `.c_str()` return values - it's just a very bad idea.

Comment: You are right thanks so much. I resolved with a std::map<std::string, std::string>.

Answer (score 1):

Does `FIRST_KEY` actually exists, or are you just using it as an example to show that you want the element at that given key?

The chances are that it doesn't work because you're storing C-strings as keys to your `std::map`. They're compared by their respective addresses, instead of the actual contents of the strings, which is likely the reason why it fails. You should be using `std::string` as a key to the map.

You should post the actual code though, otherwise you can only expect guess work. It's obvious that this piece of code is not the whole thing, because you're using `FIRST_KEY` etc. without us knowing what they are, and you have a mismatching number of brackets, as well as an incomplete statement that would produce an error.

Comment: Alternatively he can use strcmp as a map ordering function (third map template argument).